# Entity Framework Sum() performance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am having performance problems with the following Entity Framework query:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    return context.Companies
                  .Single(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
                  .DataFile.Sum(d => d.FileSize);
}
```

When tracing in SQL profiler, I see the following SQL command:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[DataFileID] AS [DataFileID], 
[Extent1].[LocalFileName] AS [LocalFileName], 
[Extent1].[ServerFileName] AS [ServerFileName], 
[Extent1].[DateUploaded] AS [DateUploaded], 
[Extent1].[FileSize] AS [FileSize], 
[Extent1].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID]
FROM [dbo].[DataFile] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[CompanyID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=16
```

From what I can see, all the data file rows are being returned (over 10,000) into memory and then the `Sum()` is occurring.

**EDIT:**

As per Patryk's suggestion, I have changed the query to this:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    return context.Companies
                  .Where(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
                  .Select(x => x.DataFiles.Sum(d => d.FileSize))
                  .Single();
}
```

And the SQL trace looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
(
    SELECT 
        SUM([Extent2].[FileSize]) AS [A1]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[DataFile] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE 
        [Extent1].[CompanyId] = [Extent2].[CompanyID]
) AS [C1]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] = 16
```

This is much better, but, essentially I just want something simple and quick like this:

```
SELECT SUM(FileSize) FROM DataFile WHERE CompanyId = 16
```

Comment: Maybe changing the query a little bit to make it look more SQL-ish would do the trick: `context.Companies.Where(c => ...).Select(x => x.DataFile.Sum(d => d.FileSize)).Single()`. That way the expression visitor might have it a tad easier and generated SQL might be better; if it doesn't help, you could manually call `AsEnumerable` after `Select` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Correct optimization, however reasoning is bad. Issue boils down to Lazy Loading.

Comment: If you want _that exact query_ than just use `context.Companies.SqlQuery("...")` - I doubt the performance difference between the two queries is significant.

Comment: @Aron In this specific case - yeah, after calling `Single` we receive a lazily-loaded collection. More often than not you can avoid a lot of problems when you re-structure your LINQ query to be more SQL-like - we can't forget that it gets transformed to SQL at one point.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek in my opinion the fault here lies with Microsoft. There are a million and one ways they could have made `.Single()`/ produce a Lazy and Linq aware return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly...either Entity Framework has improved since I last checked. The expression `.Single(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)` should by all accounts fail, since Entity Framework should fail on `Expression.Constant<Company>`. I suspect actually you've obfuscated your code listing.

The reason this is going a bit wrong is due to how `.Single(Expression)` works. Unlike most Linq `IQueryable<T>` extension methods, it evaluates straight away.

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    return context.Companies
                  .Single(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
                  .DataFile.Sum(d => d.FileSize);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
{
    Company company = context.Companies.Single(c => c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId);
    List<DataFile> dataFiles = company.DataFile
    return dataFiles.Sum(d => d.FileSize);
}
```

To break this down for you. The poor performance comes from multiple points.

The first is that `.Single()` forces the evaluation of the query, returning the `Company` (which you are after, but don't need). If you are lucky, EF might be clever and just pull that from the cache.

The second line pulls ALL the DataFiles for that Company (since `List<T>` does not have any Entity Framework code in it. Which means it HAS to pull down the whole list.

Then the third part as you know does the `.Sum()`. But if you check the actual `.Sum()` implementation, its actually `IEnumerable.Sum()`, which has nothing to do with Entity Framework. The signature is COMPLETELY different.

The one that works with ELinq is `IQueryable<T>.Sum<T,TValue>(Expression<Func<T,TValue>> projection)` and the Linq to Object one is `IEnumerable<T>.Sum<T,TValue>(Func<T.TValue> projection)`

TLDR:

In short, it takes some getting use to, to work out where LinqToEF starts and ends. The only reason your code worked was EF Lazy loading. But I would advise you turn of EF Lazy Loading when there are perf issues, as it can often hide poor understanding of Linq.

Answer (score 0):

The select statement should actually just return what the query defines,

```
select * from Extend1 where CompanyID = 16
```

Meaning, no it should only return you all rows where CompanyID = 16.

Tbh don't know how entity framework behaves, but if you do a query with nhibernate for example, a linq query `.First(p=>p.Id==16)` would do a Select Top(1)

Maybe this post helps you to optimize the generated query: [Force Entity Framework to use SQL parameterization for better SQL proc cache reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201403/force-entity-framework-to-use-sql-parameterization-for-better-sql-proc-cache-reu)