# Entity Framework query caching

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This MSDN article lists a whole bunch of ways to improve your Entity Framework performance:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx

One of its suggestions (4.3) is to convert the properties of a non-mapped object into a local variable, so that EF can cache its internal query plan.

Sounds like a great idea. So I put it to the test with a simple query that compared the performance over 10,000 iterations of an indirect property  reference in a query to a local variable. Like so:

```
[Fact]
public void TestQueryCaching()
{
    const int iterations = 1000;

    var quote = new Quote();
    using (var ctx = new CoreContext())
    {
        quote.QuoteId = ctx.Quotes.First().Id;
    }

    double indirect = 0;
    double direct = 0;

    10.Times(it =>
    {
        indirect += PerformCoreDbTest(iterations, "IndirectValue", (ctx, i) =>
           {
               var dbQuote = ctx.Quotes.First(x => x.Id == quote.QuoteId);
           }).TotalSeconds;
        direct += PerformCoreDbTest(iterations, "DirectValue", (ctx, i) =>
            {
                var quoteId = quote.QuoteId;
                var dbQuote = ctx.Quotes.First(x => x.Id == quoteId);
            }).TotalSeconds;
    });

    _logger.Debug($"Indirect seconds: {indirect:0.00}, direct seconds:{direct:0.00}");
}

protected TimeSpan PerformCoreDbTest(int iterations, string descriptor, Action<ICoreContext, int> testAction)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        using (var ctx = new CoreContext())
        {
            testAction(ctx, i);
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    _logger.DebugFormat("{0}: Took {1} milliseconds for {2} iterations",
        descriptor, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, iterations);
    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

But I'm not seeing any real performance benefit. On two different machines, these are the results over 5 iterations:

```
Machine1 - Indirect seconds: 9.06, direct seconds:9.36
Machine1 - Indirect seconds: 9.98, direct seconds:9.84
Machine2 - Indirect seconds: 22.41, direct seconds:20.38
Machine2 - Indirect seconds: 17.27, direct seconds:16.93
Machine2 - Indirect seconds: 16.35, direct seconds:16.32
```

Using a local variable - the "direct" approach that the MSDN article recommends - is maybe the tiniest bit faster (4/5 times), but not consistently, and not really by much.

Am I doing something wrong in my testing? Or is the effect really so slight that it doesn't make much difference? Or is the MSDN article basically wrong, and that way of referring to objects doesn't make any difference to query caching?

** Edits 10/9/16 **
I modified the query to (a) make it more complex, and (b) to pass in a different quoteId each time. I suspect the latter is important, as otherwise the query does in fact get cached - since there aren't any parameters. See the answer from @raderick below.

Here's the more complex test:

```
[Fact]
public void TestQueryCaching()
{
    const int iterations = 1000;

    List<EFQuote> quotes;
    using (var ctx = new CoreContext())
    {
        quotes = ctx.Quotes.Take(iterations).ToList();
    }

    double indirect = 0;
    double direct = 0;
    double iqueryable = 0;

    10.Times(it =>
    {
        indirect += PerformCoreDbTest(iterations, "IndirectValue", (ctx, i) =>
        {
            var quote = quotes[i];
            var dbQuote = ctx.Quotes
             .Include(x => x.QuoteGroup.QuoteGroupElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
             .Include(x => x.QuoteElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
             .Include(x => x.QuotePackage)
             .Include(x => x.QuoteDefinition)
             .Include(x => x.QuoteLines)
             .First(x => x.Id == quote.Id);
        }).TotalSeconds;
        direct += PerformCoreDbTest(iterations, "DirectValue", (ctx, i) =>
        {
            var quoteId = quotes[i].Id;
            var dbQuote = ctx.Quotes
                .Include(x => x.QuoteGroup.QuoteGroupElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
                .Include(x => x.QuoteElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
                .Include(x => x.QuotePackage)
                .Include(x => x.QuoteDefinition)
                .Include(x => x.QuoteLines)
                .First(x => x.Id == quoteId);
        }).TotalSeconds;
        iqueryable += PerformCoreDbTest(iterations, "IQueryable", (ctx, i) =>
        {
            var quoteId = quotes[i].Id;
            var dbQuote = ctx.Quotes
                    .Include(x => x.QuoteGroup.QuoteGroupElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
                    .Include(x => x.QuoteElements.Select(e => e.DefaultElement.DefaultChoices))
                    .Include(x => x.QuotePackage)
                    .Include(x => x.QuoteDefinition)
                    .Include(x => x.QuoteLines)
                    .Where(x => x.Id == quoteId).First();
        }).TotalSeconds;
    });

    _logger.Debug($"Indirect seconds: {indirect:0.00}, direct seconds:{direct:0.00}, iqueryable seconds:{iqueryable:0.00}");
}
```

And the results (over 10,000 total iterations) are much more like what the MSDN article above describes:

`Indirect seconds: 141.32, direct seconds:91.95, iqueryable seconds:93.96`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that this article can describe current behavior as for Entity Framework version 6, but this thing should be related to query compilation in Entity Framework into stored procedures.

When you first call some query using Entity Framework, it has to be compiled by EF into an SQL statement - either a pure SELECT query, or a procedure using `exec` and parameters for it, example:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[IssuedAt] AS [IssuedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Foo_Id] AS [Foo_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N''Some Name'' = [Extent1].[Name]) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

`@p__linq__0` is a parameter in the query, so every time you change Id in the query code, Entity Framework will pick this exact same statement from query cache and call it without trying to compile SQL for it again. On the other hand `N''Some Name'' = [Extent1].[Name]` part is equal to code `x.Name == "Some Name"`, I used a constant here so it was transformed not to query parameter, but to simple part of the query statement.

Each time you try to make a query, Entity Framework checks cache containing complied SQL statements to see if there is an already compiled statement it can re-use with parameters. If that statement is not found, Entity Framework has to compile C# query to Sql again. So if you have your queries small and fast-compiled, you won't notice anything, but if you have "hard-to-compile" queries with a lot of includes, conditions, transformations and built-in function usage, you can hit heavy penalties when your queries don't hit Entity Framework compiled queries cache.

You can see some similarity here with current work of paging without using overloads for `Skip` and `Take`, not hitting compiled query cache when changing page: [Force Entity Framework to use SQL parameterization for better SQL proc cache reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201403/force-entity-framework-to-use-sql-parameterization-for-better-sql-proc-cache-reu)

You can face this effect when using constants in your code, and its effect is quite non-obvious. Let's compare these code pieces and SQL that EntityFramework produces (I omitted class definitions for brevity, should be pretty obvious):

**Query 1**

Sample Code:

```
var result = context.Activities
                    .Where(x => x.IssuedAt >= DateTime.UtcNow && x.Id == iteration)    
                    .ToList();
```

Produced Sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[IssuedAt] AS [IssuedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Foo_Id] AS [Foo_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IssuedAt] >= (SysUtcDateTime())) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

You can see that in this case condition `x.IssuedAt >= DateTime.UtcNow` is transformed to statement `[Extent1].[IssuedAt] >= (SysUtcDateTime())`.

**Query 2**

Sample Code:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var result = context.Activities
                    .Where(x => x.IssuedAt >= now && x.Id == iteration)
                    .ToList();
```

Produced Sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[IssuedAt] AS [IssuedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Foo_Id] AS [Foo_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[IssuedAt] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0='2016-10-09 15:27:37.3798971',@p__linq__1=0
```

In this case, you can see that condition `x.IssuedAt >= now` was transformed to `[Extent1].[IssuedAt] >= @p__linq__0` - a parametrized statement, and DateTime value was passed as procedure argument.

You can clearly can see the difference here with Query 1 - condition was part of the query code without parameter, and it used built-in function for getting date time.

These 2 queries might give you a hint, that usage of constants in Entity Framework produces different queries from using only fields, properties, arguments, etc. It was a bit of synthetic example, let's check something more close to real query.

**Query 3**

Here I use enum `ActivityStatus` and want to query for Activity, that has specific Id, and I want to be able to get only activities, that have status "Active" (whatever that means).

Sample Code:

```
var result = context.Activities
    .Where(x => x.Status == ActivityStatus.Active 
                && x.Id == id)
    .ToList();
```

Produced Sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[IssuedAt] AS [IssuedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Foo_Id] AS [Foo_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

You can see, that usage of constant in condition `x.Status == ActivityStatus.Active` produces SQL `0 = [Extent1].[Status]`, which is correct. Status here is not parametrized, so if you call same query somewhere else using condition `x.Status = ActivityStatus.Pending`, that will produce another query, so calling it for the first time will cause Entity Framework query compilation. You can avoid it using **Query 4** for both.

**Query 4**

Sample Code:

```
var status = ActivityStatus.Active;

var result = context.Activities
                    .Where(x => x.Status == status
                                && x.Id == iteration)
                    .ToList();
```

Produced Sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[IssuedAt] AS [IssuedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Foo_Id] AS [Foo_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Status] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int',@p__linq__0=0,@p__linq__1=0
```

As you can see, this query statement is fully parametrized, so changing status to Pending, Active, Inactive, etc. will still use the same query from the compiled queries cache.

Depending on your coding style, you might face this issue from time to time, when same 2 queries that have only different constant value will compile a query each. I can offer you to try same query with using booleans as constants, it should produce same result - having condition unparametrized.

Comment: Great explanation - thanks for the hard work writing it up. Your point about more complex queries made a lot of sense, so I made it more complex, and I think you're basically right. See edits to my question above.

Comment: @KenSmith glad worked out for you! Did you check queries generated in SQL Server Profiler? Do they differ for Case 1 and Case 2?

Comment: Interestingly, no, not at the SQL level. The three (very complex) queries were absolutely identical at the SQL level (kdiff pronounced them so), and were all parameterized. I think that the performance boost must have been entirely on the EF side, with the bottom two able to share EF query metadata between queries, and the top one not.

Comment: @KenSmith can you also add your PerformCoreDbTest code into the question? I have a feeling, that it might affect the result somehow. You also need to warmup queries before execution for more precise result. Also breaking this test into 3 different tests might produce different results too, due to query caching.

Comment: I've added the `PerformCoreDbTest()` method up above. Agreed that a warmup would be helpful for perfect precision - but over 10,000 iterations, I think it's likely to be reasonably accurate.

Comment: @KenSmith I tried this code for complex queries that use a lot of includes for simple test classes, and the only difference I managed to get for 10000 iterations is usage of constants vs usage of fields/variables in query. So there might be some side effect for your first test, that slows things down. Do you have some kind of profiler that you can use to check, what EF method takes time in first case? Also I suggest also checking top 5% query average time and middle 90%, that might give more hints too.