# Parameterized Query from an Expression Tree in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement a dynamic filter in a generic repository (.NET Core 3.1 + EF Core 3.1)
by building an Expression Tree, but the generated SQL query is never parameterized (I'm verifying the generated query via `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"` in appsettings.json and have `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` in Startup.cs)

The code to build an Expression Tree is the following (for sake of simplicity working with string values only here):

```
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, propertyName);
        var value = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);

        var predicateBody = Expression.Equal(
            property,
            value
        );

        var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new[] { typeof(T) },
            query.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe })
        );

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
    }
```

The approach works, but values are always incorporated inside a generated SQL query and I afraid that it could lead to SQL injections.

Here is an example of a generated query:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (33ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Name], [p].[FirstName], [p].[Created], [p].[CreatedBy], [p].[Updated], [p].[UpdatedBy]
FROM [Persons] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Name] = N'smith'
```

Found a potential answer from a EF team member (@divega):
[Force Entity Framework to use SQL parameterization for better SQL proc cache reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201403/force-entity-framework-to-use-sql-parameterization-for-better-sql-proc-cache-reu#9651357), 
managed it to work with Where method, but the generated SQL is still the same.

Tried to use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core,
but it has the same issue (generated SQL query is not parameterized).

Is there a way to force Entity Framework Core to generate a parameterized query from an Expression Tree?

Comment: Have you looked at LINQkit (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and Predicate Builder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).  They may provide another path for you

Comment: Thanks for the provided links - interesting reading. As my filter is fully dynamic and generic, I didn't find a way to build a predicate for properties known only at a run-time, other then working with Expression Trees directly.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you think this can be subject to an attack. If you pass in a string like `';TRUNC Table;` that that last line of SQL becomes `WHERE [p].[Name] = N''';DELETE FROM Table;'` not `WHERE [p].[Name] = N'';DELETE FROM Table;` which seems safe enough, which is to say EF escapes the string properly. I'm probably missing something, so would be curious to know what you were thinking of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link you provided explains that EF uses a SQL parameter for variable values, so instead of creating an `Expression.Constant` for the value passed in, if you create a variable reference (which in C# is always a field reference), then you will get a parameterized query. The simplest solution seems to be to copy how the compiler handles a lambda outer scope variable reference, which is create a class object to hold the value, and reference that.

Unlike `Expression.Constant`, it isn't easy to get the actual type of the `object` parameter, so changing that to a generic type:

```
public static class IQueryableExt {
    private sealed class holdPropertyValue<T> {
        public T v;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T, TValue>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, TValue propertyValue) {
        // p
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

        // p.{propertyName}
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, propertyName);
        var holdpv = new holdPropertyValue<TValue> { v = propertyValue };
        // holdpv.v
        var value = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(holdpv), "v");

        // p.{propertyName} == holdpv.v
        var whereBody = Expression.Equal(property, value);
        // p => p.{propertyName} == holdpv.v
        var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereBody, pe);

        // Queryable.Where(query, p => p.{propertyName} == holdpv.v)
        var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new[] { typeof(T) },
            query.Expression,
            whereLambda
        );

        // query.Where(p => p.{propertyName} == holdpv.v)
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
    }
}
```

If you need to pass in an `object` instead, it is simpler to add a conversion to the proper type (which won't affect the generated SQL), rather than dynamically create the right type of `holdPropertyValue` and assign it a value, so:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals2<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, object propertyValue) {
    // p
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    // p.{propertyName}
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, propertyName);

    var holdpv = new holdPropertyValue<object> { v = propertyValue };
    // Convert.ChangeType(holdpv.v, p.{propertyName}.GetType())
    var value = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(holdpv), "v"), property.Type);

    // p.{propertyName} == Convert.ChangeType(holdpv.v, p.{propertyName}.GetType())
    var whereBody = Expression.Equal(property, value);
    // p => p.{propertyName} == Convert.ChangeType(holdpv.v, p.{propertyName}.GetType())
    var whereLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(whereBody, pe);

    // Queryable.Where(query, p => p.{propertyName} == Convert.ChangeType(holdpv.v, p.{propertyName}.GetType()))
    var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new[] { typeof(T) },
        query.Expression,
        whereLambda
    );

    // query.Where(query, p => p.{propertyName} == Convert.ChangeType(holdpv.v, p.{propertyName}.GetType()))
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the provided answer! Works perfect on strings. However for objects there was still an issue with a conversion and for example on int value system throws `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.
lambda_method(Closure )`.

Comment: Got around by the following code 
`
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)property.Member).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);
var valueConverted = converter.ConvertFrom(propertyValue);
var holdpv = new holdPropertyValue<object> { v = valueConverted };
`
that made your answer to work super smoothly.

Comment: @Vitaly If you pass the wrong type (e.g. a `string` when the field is an `Int32`) then that will happen. I tested the code with an `int` column, but I passed an `int` to the `WhereEquals2` method. I assumed you would pass in the type that matches the column's type.

Comment: You are totally right - your code works perfect. Was an issue on my side as I'm parsing params from a query string. Thanks again!

Comment: @Vitaly Ah - perhaps the parameter should be a `string` instead of an `object` and then you convert to an `object` of the right type as you indicated :)