# EF 6 Connection pool and stored query strings RAM leak

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 problems.

First one is that Connection pool and (OracleConnectionImpl) is growing steadily over time, till it reaches out of memory exception. As you can see on the image, it has 90 MB over 3-4 hours of running.

I am using short lived contexts everywhere, but it keeps on growing and never clears itself. Is there any way for me to clear it?

Second one is that EF stores too much duplicates of string queries over time.
It mostly stores those which come from .Reload() function, because it is not paramterized, it hardcode the ID into the query.
And then there are strings like "ID" which is somewhere cached 2947x.

Is there any way for the .Reload() function to make it parametrized, or to clear all of those stored strings?

This app is refreshing warehouse jobs and palletes every few seconds, to keep it in sync for all machines and I am not aware of better way than .Reload() because of WPF bindings.

[image: dotMemory Snapshot]

[image: String duplicates]

Edit 1

I have simple helper function for reloading many intities at once, even one extension. It doesnt matter that it is passed as object, because the same problem remains even with the last example.

```cs
     public static void ReloadEntities(bool dispatch, params IEnumerable<object>[] entities)
        {
            using (var ctx = new eWMSEntities())
            {
                if (dispatch)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
                    {
                        entities.SelectMany(x => x.Select(s => s)).ToList().ForEach(entity =>
                       {
                           ctx.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
                           ctx.Entry(entity).Reload();
                           ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
                       });
                    }, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    entities.SelectMany(x => x.Select(s => s)).ToList().ForEach(entity =>
                    {
                        ctx.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
                        ctx.Entry(entity).Reload();
                        ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
                    });
                }
                ctx.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static void ReloadEntity(this object entity, bool dispatch)
        {
            using (var ctx = new eWMSEntities())
            {
                ctx.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
                if (dispatch)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
                    {
                        ctx.Entry(entity).Reload();
                    }, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Entry(entity).Reload();
                }
                ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
                ctx.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

```cs
    while (true && JobLines.Contains(line))
            {
                using (var ctx = new eWMSEntities())
                {
                    ctx.T_JOB_LINES.attach(line);
                    ctx.entry(line).Reload();
                }
await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
```

This is snapshot after 3 days of running
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: It would help to see a couple typical examples of code where you are loading a view and performing an update/insert and what you consider to be short lived contexts.

Comment: @StevePy Hi, I have added sample code how I am reloading entities. In this particular program I am not doing any inserts, or updates. I am only keeping data online to display it.

Comment: If it disposable (since you are "using" ctx), why do you have to force a ctx.dispose()? The end of the using should dispose it gracefully.

Comment: EF6 doesn't make bulk operations. I think that's why you are seeing a lot of duplicated strings when reloading. You could try something like [EF Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus). If any of your queries uses Skip, Take or Contains you shuld see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651357/3111429). As for the connection pool, verify the max allowed number of connections in your server.

Comment: @KevinCook That was just desperate attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: @KautskyLozano Not really. I am not using skip, take, nor contains. I am using at most Any to keep all my queries parametrized. Only thing that is not parametrized is ctx.Reload(), because I am not really sure how to replace it, nor how to make it parametrized

Comment: Could you make a test application and send a github link?

Comment: @BorisGappov I cannot replicate it with small scaled application and I sadly cannot share source code for this WMS app.

Comment: This is good, you're halfway to identifying the cause. Most likely you need to break the application into parts, into modules, into services

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommend but if there are no any other solution...
Maybe you can try

```
GC.Collect();
```

Let system force to collect something didn't important in your memory.

Comment: Hello, thanks for idea, but I have already tried to force GC, but it works well as of now. Just the EF doesnt get cleaned.

Comment: I found something looks similar about clean nulls and repeated.
Maybe this could helps a little...
[link](https://christianarg.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/entityframework-refreshall-loaded-entities-from-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Unit of work" pattern - it will solve many problems. I did not find for WPF, but found for [ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but it doesnt really help