# server side paging and OrderBy with DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Is there anybody who can tell how to use DbContext for to do server side paging and orderby functionality. I used Where clause to filter the record. Need something similar so that I'd only get the restricted number of records.

thanks in advance

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take

Comment: hi, I don't have MyDbContext available within my repository. how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution. May be its what you're looking for:

```
public const int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
// LINQ query
    var query = from m in db.Products
    select m;
    // Set the total count
    // so GridView knows how many pages to create
    e.Arguments.TotalRowCount = query.Count();
    // Get only the rows we need for the page requested
    query = query.Skip(GridView1.PageIndex * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
    e.Result = query;
}
```

[Effective Paging using LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10170/effective-paging-using-linq-in-Asp-Net.aspx)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in EF using the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346801.aspx) and [`Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155995.aspx) builder methods, or using LINQ `Skip` and `Take` after calling `OrderBy`.

Comment: this what I'm trying to do 
`code`
IQueryable<T> LoadData(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                                        int currentPage = 0, int pageSize = 0,string includeProperties = "")
        {IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).AsNoTracking(); 
IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery;
IQueryable<T> returnValue = null;
if (orderBy != null)
query = orderBy(query);
if (pageSize>0)
returnValue = query.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).AsQueryable();return returnValue;}
`code`