# Request only first item Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm looking for the most efficiant method to call the first and only the first item from a SQL Server database using Entityframework and linq.

I'm currently using

```
public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(Guid userID)
    {
        UserProfile oProfile = null;

        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            var profiles = from c in context.UserProfiles where c.UserID == userID select c;

            if(profiles.Any())
            {
                oProfile = profiles.First();
            }
        }

        return oProfile;
    }
```

This however from what I can tell takes two DB ops to complete, one to check if the record exists and a second to return it. I'm sure there has to be a better pattern / method and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: var profile = (from c in context.UserProfiles where c.UserID == userID select c).First();

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault` it it will translate to `SELECT TOP 1` and results in being `NULL` if it's not found so you can lose the `Any` extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple: Use FirstOrDefault().
When there is no entry it will return null (like you have already), else it'll return the first entry. If you don't want your variable to take the null value, use a substitute in between.

edit:
Your code could be equally replaced with the following code, just that this one will just query once against the database.

```
public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(Guid userID)
{
    UserProfile oProfile = null;

    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        oProfile = (from c in context.UserProfiles where c.UserID == userID select c).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return oProfile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` without calling `.Any()`

```
var profile = (from c in context.UserProfiles where c.UserID == userID select c).First();
```

`First()` throws an exception if no records returned but `FirstOrDefault()` returns null in that case

Both will generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ...
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one item should exist (as it looks in this case) then you should consider using Single(). Single will return the first item but throw an exception if more than one item exists - this can help maintain data quality if only a single item should exist.

If only one item should exist but it is optional then use SingleOrDefault which will act as Single but return null if no item exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Take method:

[Entity Framework/Linq to SQL: Skip & Take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take)

It will only require one hit to the database.

Comment: any reason this over Martins's (FirstOrDefault) answer?