# Best way to display profiles results in MVC in a paged way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm hesitating and thinking about how to display the result searches.

The situation is following:
I have a website, where a user can fill in few texboxes and based on that perform a search. And then i would like to display him the results in a paged way: something like:

photo, name, age    |     photo, name, age    | photo, name age

So i would like to have a 3 columns, and then probably 5 rows.

But I don't know, what is the best way to represent something like this, is there a best approach etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's so many approaches you can go with from many different perspectives. We could really be talking about it for ages. But, in a nutshell, you can implement paging at the presentation layer, at the controller level, at the business logic layer or at the data layer. Basically, the lower you go down your application layer the better performance you'll get, there's no much difference between implementing paging at the controller and the business logic layer when it comes to performance but design wise it's better to keep these concerns at the business logic layer for better maintainability and scalability. You will get much better performance if paging is implemented at the data layer, specially if you have a lot of data to display and then tell the data access layer to fetch just the page of data your application is interested in. Using other approaches will force you to retrieve all data from the backend store which might result in unnecessary bandwidth consumption and data transfers. See this example below where I'm doing the paging at the data layer level..

### Example

#### SQL Query

I'm using a custom data access layer that runs the sql query below to query a large amount of devices...

```
select top (@pagesize) * 
from
    (
       select row_number() over(order by d.Name) as RowId
              , d.Id
              , d.Name
              , d.IsDeleted
              , dt.Id as DeviceTypeId
              , dt.Name as DeviceTypeName
        from Devices d
        left join DeviceTypes dt on dt.Id = d.DeviceTypeId
    )
    as o
    where o.RowId <= (@page * @pagesize) and o.RowId > ((@page - 1) * @pagesize)
```

The query is simple you specify the page size(records per data page) and the data page to retrieve (first page, the second page, etc.). This query is run by my data access layer which constructs business ojects and pass them to the Business Logic Layer

#### Business Logic

Then, in the my business logic I called the devices data object to retrieve the data page I'm interested in. The following method does that job...

```
  public IList<DeviceBO> GetAllDevices(int page, out int count)
  {
        count = DataProvider.Devices.GetAllDevicesCount();
        return DataProvider.Devices.GetAllDevices(page, BusinessConstants.GRID_PAGE_SIZE);
  }
```

Very straight-forward operation. Yet, there's a few things to notice. One, that I'm making two round-trips to the database; one to get the count of all devices and the second one to retrieve a data page of devices. We can argue that this could be avoided which is true by doing a single trip to the database, but in my case it is a very quick query that runs in less than 1 second and believe me...I have over a million records. The call to the `GetAllDevicesCount` does nothing more than a sql `select count(Id) from dbo.Devices`

Also notice that `DataProvider` is just a factory object. You don't really need to worry about the implementation details. And `BusinessConstants.GRID_PAGE_SIZE` simple returns a number, the standard page size used across my application (I've got a few grids/tables) and it's just a way to keep things in one place in case I want to change the page size across all grids/tables later on.

#### Controller

Then I have defined a device controller that exposes the following action method (Manage)...

```
public class DevicesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Manage(string currentPage)
    {
        return process_device_list(currentPage);
    }

    //this method was created as a result of code re-factoring since it is used in several other action methods not shown here
    private ActionResult process_device_list(string currentPage, bool redirect = false)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int page = 1;

        if (!int.TryParse(currentPage, out page))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPage))
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");

            page = 1;
        }

        var model = new DeviceManagementListModel();
        model.Devices = BusinessFactory.DevicesLogic.GetAllDevices(page, out count);
        model.ActualCount = count;
        model.CurrentPage = page;

        if (!redirect)
            return View(model);
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { @currentPage = currentPage });
    }

}
```

#### View

The view is pretty much just HTML and razor syntax, there's nothing interesting going on there. Perhaps, the footer of the table/grid is where more interesting things happen since the paging markup is define there....

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
         <div class="pager">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Devices", FormMethod.Get)){
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CurrentPage, new { title = "Enter a page number to change the page results" })
                <input type="submit" value="Go" title="Change the current page result" />
                            }

          </div>
          <div class="total">
               @Model.ActualCount record(s) found
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

And this is how it looks...

[image]

Notice in the `tfoot` section of the table in my view that I have added a `form` element that makes a `GET` request to my action method `Manage` rather than a `POST` request. This is useful to provide a nice restful url where users can specified manually the page they're interested in...

[image]

I hope it helps you get some basic ideas

Comment: Yes, i'm just curious how to arrange it, i mean i retrieve that i have to keep it somewhere and meanwhile make a result set with paging ...

Comment: And what if i'm using EF it stil should be the same? I mean the DAL, because, I'm not sure if i can specify the data to be retreived by pages ... and imagine, if during the change, some extra devices should be displayed for example they became active (and you want to display all activate devices) first in general you get 100 results 10 per page, 10 pages, but after few pages it is 105 devices that are online

Comment: this is just a template for your solution. In EF you can use `Skip` and `Take`. And if you want to add any criteria, well, that's why we have `where` clauses in sql, just make sure that the same criteria matches the count query. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Yes, more or less, just one clarifiaction about EF getting per page: will it be something like this: (from u in context.users where user.Online==true select u).Take(10)

Comment: `Skip(PageSize * PageIndex)`...assuming that `PageIndex` is zero-based and then `Take(PageSize)`....have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take