# Creating an appropriate index for server-side paging query

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (100000) 
    [Filter1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Filter1].[FIELD1] AS [FIELD1], 
    [Filter1].[FIELD2] AS [FIELD2], 
    [Filter1].[FIELD3] AS [FIELD3], 
    [Filter1].[FIELD4] AS [FIELD4], 
    ...
    [Filter1].[FIELD30] AS [FIELD30], 
    FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
         [Extent1].[FIELD1] AS [FIELD1],
         [Extent1].[FIELD2] AS [FIELD2],
         [Extent1].[FIELD3] AS [FIELD3]
         ...
         [Filter1].[FIELD30] AS [FIELD30], 
         row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
         FROM [dbo].[TABLE] AS [Extent1]
         WHERE (N'VALUE1' <> [Extent1].[**FIELD2**]
         AND (N'VALUE2' <> ([Extent1].[**FIELD3**])
         AND ([Extent1].[**FIELD4**] IN (VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, .... VALUE9)))
         AS [Filter1]
    WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Filter1].[ID] ASC
```

Due to the amount of rows that need to be selected (a few million) I am doing it in batches, hence the row_number filtering. Currently the query analyzer says that a Clustered index scan is conducted on FIELD1. Still I would like better performance which is why I've tried indexing on the fields in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

What I've tried so far:

Non-clustered indexes on

```
FIELD2 ASC,
FIELD3 ASC,
FIELD4 ASC,
ID ASC
```

And every possible permutation. The query execution time doubles and triples.

Why is this happening and what sort of index can I create to speed this up?

By the way, I'm running SQL Server 2005, so can't use filtered indexes. Compatibility level is 7.0.

Comment: you could drop the where clause since it doesn't do anything

Comment: Your `SELECT TOP` and `ROW_NUMBER` combination is redundant.  If you have a clustered index on `FIELD1`, then `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]`is forcing SQL to re-order the table.  I'd drop the row_number() and just use your `TOP N`.

Comment: @Andrew, this makes sense, however, removing row_number() increases the duration by 30 seconds even though the execution plan is shorter.

Comment: Doesn't look like the query design is given good time. before creating/updating indexes can you actually describe the Table structure, current indexes, current data volume, current execution time. by "execution time" i mean execution time taken by the query from SSMS. not the total time taken by the client to render the data  to user. BTW, why top (100000) ? is this business need or you added it for some performance enhancement. selecting all the data in sub query and the filter it in outer query is the first thing i notice not right with this query.

Comment: My feeling is that throwing more indexes at this query is not going to help you. You are using `<>` and `IN` in the inner query which tends to kill selectivity. This is kind of supported by your observation that any possible permutation of that compound index did not help. @AnupShah is right, you are reordering the whole table in the inner query then filtering it out in outer query. If possible create clustered index on ID instead of FIELD1, that should help.

Comment: @AnupShah, database is legacy so is not pretty. The table in question has 130 columns and around 2 million rows. Field1 is primary key instead of ID because legacy apps change the ID periodically... so clustered index is on Field1. Total time from SSMS is: CPU time 26373 ms, elapsed time 162284. The reason for top (100000) is due to server-side paging. Business need is to write a file with 1,500,000 rows- obviously you can't load the whole set in memory so I am using what in Entity Framework we call paging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take).

Comment: @TomT see comment above. ID cannot be clustered index- what would be the next best thing?

Comment: @CircularReference, in the query "WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 0", you must have Variable on the right side instead 0. because for every next fetch the code will be sending you the last row number and subsequent selects will be next 100000 rows from that number. is that right ?

Comment: @AnupShah, correct for the next batch it would be "WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > 100000"

Comment: @CircularReference, are the Where Filter values for the Column "FIELD2","FIELD3""FIELD4" are STring or Numeric or INT. so basically what is the datatype for those column.

Comment: @CircularReference, if your only problem is to generate a file, why not use SqlDataReader instead EF and get rid of the paging altogether?

Comment: @AnupShah "FIELD2" is char(2), "FIELD3" char(25), "FIELD4" (int)

Comment: @TomT, of course SqlDataReader would speed this up dramatically, but my question is if I can do anything from an index point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here was to ignore indexes on where and order by clauses and instead change the order by clause to "ORDER BY [Filter1].[FIELD2] ASC" where a clustered index already existed. In this way 100k rows were returned in 3 seconds. Ordering within the file was changed, however server-side paging was not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I did some testing with dummy data on my local. I am making this recommendations considering you do not have any index on that table right now. or if you have please drop before you do any test with this suggestions.

1) [FIELD1] is not being used in any where filters. Make that Primary KEY as NON-CLUSTERED.

2) Now make Clustered index on columns (FIELD2 ASC,FIELD3 ASC,FIELD4 ASC)

3) You have ROW_NUMBER function ordered by on [ID] column. So use that [Row_Number] in outer order by clause instead [ID]

4) Change the Where Filters Order in the Query. Keep the [FIELD4] filter very first and use [FIELD2] and [FIELD3] filters after that.

5) If The Data Type of Columns [FIELD2] AND [FIELD3] is INT/NUMERIC/DATE then you can replace the "<>" operator with  combination of "(> OR  <=)".

6) If the Datatype of Columns [FIELD2] AND [FIELD3] is STRING then leave those WHERE filters with "<>" operator.

check these suggestions on [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c1ed/1). This one does not have any data but explains above index and query suggestions

With above suggestions you will get the "Index Seek" and this should give you the good performance improvement. in my testing with dummy data of 2M row table it is returning 50k rows in 2 seconds in SSMS.

Comment: Creating a wide clustered index on that table could affect performance as it is updated hundreds of times per day and already has more than two dozen indexes. In the end the solution was to do  "ORDER BY [Filter1].[FIELD2] ASC", where the clustered index currently sits. This resulted in retrieving 100k rows in 3 seconds, which I'm very happy with. I am up-voting your answer anyway, as I didn't know about SQL FIDDLE :)

Comment: yes, that is why very first thing I asked was to explain any existing indexes. again if you have dozens of Indexes you should thing about it more seriously because my guess is you might have postpone the current issue. but good to know that you have found immediate solution with minimal changes.