# Entity Framework: Skip/Take functionality

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm just curious how Skip and Take functions work in Entity Framework (using EF 6.1).

If I do:

```
db.Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(maxPageSize).ToList();
```

I get some list (noticed that one event is completely gone).

If I do:

```
db.Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Skip(0).Take(maxPageSize).ToList();
```

I get another list and that gone event in previous query is present here.

Anyone has idea why do I have to `Skip()` **ZERO** entities in order to `Take()` what I'm supposed to take? It makes almost no sense (at least for me)...

P.S. I can't use SQL Server Profiler to check what queries are generated.

Comment: Without a working example, its hard to see credibility in this claim.. `Skip(0)` shouldn't do anything

Comment: Tip: Attach a function to `DbContext.Database.Log` (`Action<string>`) to see generated SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework/Linq to SQL: Skip & Take](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take)

Comment: @Sayse, I'm not really a troll or a liar. I wouldn't have asked that if I hadn't seen it myself. I too think that `Skip(0)` should do nothing. + I've seen question you've seen as duplicate, but that doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @YOhan - I didn't say you were I just said it sounds hard to believe, which is why I went in search of information.. there are other links on the right in the related column that may be of interest. The one I proposed as duplicate seems to have the exact same issue as you

Comment: @YOhan please don't assume bad faith, I think you just ran into Sagan's "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence". As mentioned by others, in this context, although `Skip(0)` may modify the query (if not optimised away), the result set should be identical. If it's not, we need more information on what you're doing to be able to explain why that isn't true. It's not because we assume you're lying or trolling.

Comment: @Basic the results can be different in cases where the last item of the "Take" is a tie on the "OrderBy". I'll provide an answer with more detail. I wanted to note to here that you don't need SQL Server Profiler to see the query. Set a variable equal to "db.Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Skip(0).Take(maxPageSize)" and the debugger will show you the query emitted at that point when you hover over the variable. There are other ways to dump the SQL as well that you can look into through the debugger.

Comment: @BrandonBarkley In that case, the order of the items is undefined (by definition!) and there are no guarantees as to which item will be included. I don't see how it could add or remove items, however.

Comment: @Basic I agree that there are no guarantees with the SQL that is actually generated. My point was that it is easy to assume that Skip(0) would be equivalent to not providing the Skip directive at all. I'm not sure about "disappearing" items in the original question, but in my results one item "disappeared" because it was excluded from the ordering without a Skip and also excluded from Skip(page1NumberOfItems) next page due to the difference in the way the query was built. Using Skip(0) caused it to appear on the first page and the duplicated item only appeared on page 2.

Comment: @BrandonBarkley Interesting manifestation thanks for the example, and for highlighting why context/usage is so important to answer questions like these. I know I'm being a pedant, but I still argue Skip(0) didn't modify the result set. It returned exactly what it was given - a list ending with items in an undefined order. In theory, you could run the code without the Skip(0) and depending on SQL Server/EF internal state, be likely to see the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is mostly correct in describing how emitted queries different though the details can vary. I have commonly seen the entity framework emit the query as "TOP (@maxPageSize) .... WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] > @skip" which is probably the same difference, but I am not 100% certain if it generates the same query execution plan.

The important difference to clearly note is that this can produce differing results when your "ORDER BY" does not contain a unique column name.

In code that I had written, we omitted the "Skip" when the @skip value was 0. We had one entry appear as the final entry. If you then went to the next page where the @skip value was applied, the same entry appeared as the first item on that page. The "tied" item that should have been in at least one of those positions never appeared. Here is the SQL that each emitted:

No skip (generated on page 1):

```
SELECT TOP ({take number}) [Extent1].[Table1ID] AS [Table1ID], {snip a lot of other columns}
        FROM  [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Table2ID] = [Extent2].[Table2ID]
        WHERE ({my where clause conditions})
        ORDER BY [Extent2].[MySortColumn] ASC
```

Skip:

```
SELECT TOP ({take number}) [Filter1].[Table1ID], {snip a lot of other columns}
        FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Table1ID] AS [Table1ID], {snip a lot of other columns}, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent2].[MySortColumn] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM  [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Table2ID] = [Extent2].[Table2ID]
            WHERE ({my where clause conditions})
        )  AS [Filter1]
        WHERE [Filter1].[row_number] > {skip number}
        ORDER BY [Filter1].[MySortColumn] ASC
```

The important take away is to go all the way back to "SQL 101" and remember that [without "order by", order is not guaranteed](https://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2010/06/27/sql-101-without-order-by-order-is-not-guaranteed.aspx). This difference in emitting causing an item to be duplicated on multiple pages of a grid while another item never shows up at all has made me see that this is even more paramount in Entity Framework where the exact SQL produced is not as directly in your control and **can differ in future EF versions unexpectedly**.

You can currently avoid this by always including Skip(0) which will emit the second query but with {skip number} simply being zero. This appears to, in my tests, always emit the same ordering for tiebreakers using the default rules of T-SQL. I believe it is not best practice to assume that this will necessarily work in future versions of Entity Framework as such though. I would suggest that instead, you consider exploring a [tie-breaking strategy](http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/t-sql-tiebreakers) of your own. In my case, it should be possible to break the tie on "Table1ID" as that represents a unique identity primary key column. The attached article gives suggestions for more complicated situations though.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer as this actually explains the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is completely different queries generated. In first case you simply take top N rows:

```
SELECT TOP(@maxPageSize) ...
FROM [Events]
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

In second case row number is used to filter ordered rows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], ...
      FROM [Events])
WHERE [ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @skip + 1 AND @skip + @maxPageSize
ORDER BY [ROW_NUMBER]
```

[ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) returns row numbers starting from 1. If page size is 5 then first query will return you top 5 rows, as expected. Second query will return you rows with numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. So, there should not be any difference between these two queries when @skip parameter equals to zero.

Make sure you are really executing exactly specified queries with exactly same parameters. Make sure Events table have exactly same data when you run these queries. Check if you are using latest versions of assemblies.

Comment: Erm... Query is already sorted by date BEFORE `Take()`, that's why I'm confused. Supposedly query should return top results from ordered query, am I wrong? That WHERE condition (and `Skip(0)` whatsoever) looks completely irrelevant in my case.. Checked all the records in debugger - all are the same.. Stumped. In any case, thank you for detailed response, I'm marking this as answer and still wondering if something's wrong on our side or in EF itself..

Comment: @YOhan I think EF is pretty good with such simple queries. I added some possible reasons why results may differ. I suggest you to try executing both queries consequentially and verify results with nothing in the middle. Please update question when you find reason of problem - it may be helpful for others)