# Where does EF linq skip / take execute?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have:

```
IQueryable<Entity> query = (from e in Context.Set<TEntity>() select e);
IEnumerable<TEntity> result = query.OrderBy(x=>x.Property).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

The OrderBy/Skip/Take return an `IEnumerable<T>`. I am concerned that what will happen is that all the results will be returned, and then Linq will be used to take only a portion of them.

My question is: Are the OrderBy/Skip and Take included in the issued SQL query so that only the requested subset of the total results is returned?

Comment: Did you try it while monitoring your SQL Server? [Some insights here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822878/entity-framework-skip-take-functionality).

Comment: IQueryable is compiled to sql. So, yes, only request subset of the total results is returned

Comment: As a side topic, I recommend you to read about deferred execution. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: I will do some reading, I needed this answer in a hurry. Thank you all very much for your answers and comments. Which one to pick as the answer..?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The OrderBy/Skip/Take return an `IEnumerable<T>`

`OrderBy` [has an overload that returns `IOrderedQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549264(v=vs.100).aspx), not only `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. So do [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb357513(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300906(v=vs.100).aspx). C# compiler is smart enough to prefer these overloads to ones returning `IEnumerable<T>`, as long as you do not force it to do otherwise. The operation is going to be performed in the database, as long as you do not convert it to `IEnumerable` too early.

Answer (score 2):

> Are the OrderBy/Skip and Take included in the issued SQL query so that only the requested subset of the total results is returned?

Yes, all of these methods are supported and they will be converted to SQL.The whole list is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx),as you can see there are overloads of each method that takes `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are translated to SQL and executed against the DB directly.