# EF and proper pagination - is there a better way then this?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

Let say we have a View that returns ~ 30 000 records, we want to present returned rows in a Jquery Datatable with pagination, with all data like - how many rows there are totally, how many after our filtration (if any) have been applied and so on - filled is there any alternative to use beside:

```
ourQuery.Skip(currentPaginationSkipValue).Take(currentPaginationDisplayValue);
```

??

I’m asking this because Entity generates pretty HUGE Sql for Skip and Take:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[CentralId] AS [CentralId], 
    [Project1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Project1].[Concession] AS [Concession], 
    [Project1].[Group] AS [Group], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[IsCooperating] AS [IsCooperating], 
    [Project1].[IsOffice] AS [IsOffice], 
    [Project1].[IsSalesLocked] AS [IsSalesLocked], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[Nip] AS [Nip], 
    [Project1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [Project1].[ProfileType] AS [ProfileType], 
    [Project1].[Regon] AS [Regon], 
    [Project1].[StatusType] AS [StatusType], 
    [Project1].[Street] AS [Street], 
    [Project1].[TerritorialDivision] AS [TerritorialDivision], 
    [Project1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[CentralId] AS [CentralId], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], [Project1].[Concession] AS [Concession], [Project1].[Nip] AS [Nip], [Project1].[Regon] AS [Regon], [Project1].[IsSalesLocked] AS [IsSalesLocked], [Project1].[ProfileType] AS [ProfileType], [Project1].[StatusType] AS [StatusType], [Project1].[City] AS [City], [Project1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], [Project1].[Street] AS [Street], [Project1].[Phone] AS [Phone], [Project1].[IsCooperating] AS [IsCooperating], [Project1].[TerritorialDivision] AS [TerritorialDivision], [Project1].[Group] AS [Group], [Project1].[IsOffice] AS [IsOffice], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[CentralId] AS [CentralId], 
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent1].[Concession] AS [Concession], 
            [Extent1].[Nip] AS [Nip], 
            [Extent1].[Regon] AS [Regon], 
            [Extent1].[IsSalesLocked] AS [IsSalesLocked], 
            [Extent1].[ProfileType] AS [ProfileType], 
            [Extent1].[StatusType] AS [StatusType], 
            [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
            [Extent1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], 
            [Extent1].[Street] AS [Street], 
            [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
            [Extent1].[IsCooperating] AS [IsCooperating], 
            [Extent1].[TerritorialDivision] AS [TerritorialDivision], 
            [Extent1].[Group] AS [Group], 
            [Extent1].[IsOffice] AS [IsOffice], 
            1 AS [C1], 
            STR( CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS decimal(19,0))) AS [C2]
            FROM (SELECT 
    [View_Customers].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [View_Customers].[Guid] AS [Guid], 
    [View_Customers].[CentralId] AS [CentralId], 
    [View_Customers].[ShortName] AS [ShortName], 
    [View_Customers].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [View_Customers].[IsActive] AS [IsActive], 
    [View_Customers].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [View_Customers].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [View_Customers].[Concession] AS [Concession], 
    [View_Customers].[Nip] AS [Nip], 
    [View_Customers].[Regon] AS [Regon], 
    [View_Customers].[Pesel] AS [Pesel], 
    [View_Customers].[IsSalesLocked] AS [IsSalesLocked], 
    [View_Customers].[IsVisitLocked] AS [IsVisitLocked], 
    [View_Customers].[CooperationType] AS [CooperationType], 
    [View_Customers].[ProfileType] AS [ProfileType], 
    [View_Customers].[CustomerType] AS [CustomerType], 
    [View_Customers].[StatusType] AS [StatusType], 
    [View_Customers].[Country] AS [Country], 
    [View_Customers].[City] AS [City], 
    [View_Customers].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], 
    [View_Customers].[Street] AS [Street], 
    [View_Customers].[BuildingNumber] AS [BuildingNumber], 
    [View_Customers].[FlatNumber] AS [FlatNumber], 
    [View_Customers].[Province] AS [Province], 
    [View_Customers].[District] AS [District], 
    [View_Customers].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
    [View_Customers].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [View_Customers].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
    [View_Customers].[IsCooperating] AS [IsCooperating], 
    [View_Customers].[TerritorialDivision] AS [TerritorialDivision], 
    [View_Customers].[Group] AS [Group], 
    [View_Customers].[ProfileTypeEntryCode] AS [ProfileTypeEntryCode], 
    [View_Customers].[IsOffice] AS [IsOffice]
    FROM [dbo].[View_Customers] AS [View_Customers]) AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] = 1
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 20000
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC
```

and there seem to be a linear relationship here:

```
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 20000
```

the bigger the 20000 value the slower the query, for example when - instead of 20000 I use 200, the query will execute in 100 ms, for 2000 it will take 800 ms for 20000 it will take 2000 ms, and with 200000 it will take 12 seconds and so on.

Question is - is it possible to somehow, make this speed constant so no matter how much will it have to skip, it will take the same amount of time?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take, maybe here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46940/entity-framework-skip-and-take-too-slow and here http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/02/18/writing-efficient-queries-with-entity-framework-code-first-part-3.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't that go to coderview?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair

Thanks but I already read those earlier... so it would seem there is no real way to optimize this too much... ?

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: @GertArnold

EF6, SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: @user2384366 sorry for being a bit unexact, I meant http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, I think there's not much you can do. But how realistic is this? If there is a filter that passes 30,000 records, how will someone navigate to the last 10 entries? I think you have to make sure that the filter always narrows down the results and apply ordering so the most interesting records will show on top of the list.

Comment: If this is a web application you need to have server side pagination and filtering..

Comment: @GertArnold
That's what I feared. You are right of course, we should filter the desired results first - unfortunately all of our lists are designed in a way that use total row number count + dynamic loading on list scroll event. I thought pagination could speed things up.

Comment: @tarzanbappa
Yes it i a web application (or rather Silverlight application) could you be more specific what do you have in mind?