# LINQ EF AND VS2017

Tags: linq

I wrote a query and worked on LINQPAD

```
from x in FacilityData
from y in FavInformation
where y.UserID == 1 && x.ID == y.FacilityID 
select new
{
    xID = x.ID,
    xDistrictName = (from y in _Ilcelers
                     where y.ID == x.DistrictID
                     select y.IlceAd).FirstOrDefault(),
    xName = x.Name,
    Value = (from o in Tags
             from p in  Table_tags
             where o.Prefix != null && o.Prefix == p._NAME && o.Facility == y.FacilityID
             orderby p.İd descending
             select new
             {
                 FType = o.TagType,
                 Name = o.TagsName,
                 Value = p._VALUE,
                 Time = p._TIMESTAMP

             }).Take(Tags.Count(h => h.Facility == y.FacilityID))
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOpGU.png)

**the result is perfect**

but does not work in visual studio,

```
Value = (from o in DB.Tags
    from p in DB.table_tags
    where o.Prefix != null && o.Prefix == p.C_NAME && o.Facility == 11
    orderby p.id descending
    select new
    {
        FType=o.TagType,
        Name = o.TagsName,
        Value = p.C_VALUE,
        Time = p.C_TIMESTAMP
    }).Take(Tags.Count(h => h.Facility == y.FacilityID))
```

and it gives an error.
I guess the part with ***.Take()*** doesn't work because it's linq to EF.

error:

> `Limit must be a DbConstantExpression or a Db Parameter Reference Expression. Parametre name: count]`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aljyp.png)

thank you have a good day

Comment: What happens if you `.Take()` a constant value, like 2?

Comment: .Take() value should not be constant, value is variable.

Comment: I meant, for the sake of an experiment. What happens if you try evaluate `Tags.Count(h => h.Facility == y.FacilityID)` before the whole query?

Comment: Unfortunately, the value remains constant when I do, except for the query.
There are 3 values ​​in some locations, some in 2.
So I need to get the last values ​​from each location.

Comment: Wait, but why do you even need `.Take()` if you want to take all the items you have from `Where()`? Furthermore, why does your LINQPad query have a `o.Facility == y.FacilityID` in `.Where()` and the VS features a constant value instead of `y.FacilityID`? Perhaps you should get it back and remove the `.Take()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870091/entity-framework-linq-to-sql-skip-take Maybe you can find your answer here according to your error message

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I will just throw it in. If you are talking about linq to ef/sql, it is possible they dont know a thing about C#. If take() would be the problem try to get the select result local first by doing .tolist(). Afterwards use your take funtion.

```
.ToList().Take(Tags.Count(h => h.Facility == y.FacilityID))
```

Comment: no ! work :( it gives an error => Limit must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression.
Parameter Name: count